# How to efficiently XML parse in R

Tags: r, xml, parallel-processing

I use R to parse XML data from a website. I have list of 20,000 rows with URLs from which I need to extract data. I have a code which gets the job done using a for loop, but it's very slow (takes approx. 12 hours). I thought of using parallel processing (I have access to several CPUs) to speed it up, but I cannot make it work properly. Would it be more efficient using a data table instead of a data frame? Is there any way to speed the process up? Thanks!

```
for (i in  1:nrow(list)) {
  t <- xmlToDataFrame(xmlParse(read_xml(list$path[i]))) #Read the data into a file
  t$ID <- list$ID[i]
  emptyDF <- bind_rows(all, t) #Bind all into one file
  if (i / 10 == floor(i / 10)) {
    print(i)
  }  #print every 10th value to monitor progress of the loop
}
```

Comment: Thank you. each iteration of t have several rows, however. Is it still possible to make it a vector? and how could I bind them together outside of the loop?

Comment: You're parsing your XML 3 times. I think one call to `xmlToDataFrame` would be enough.

Comment: Sorry, I misspoke earlier, Make "t" a **list** and then store the data frames as elements in the list, `t[[i]]`.  Then outside the loop: `bind_rows(t)`

Comment: Thanks! if at all possible, could you show me how to do so with my code?

Comment: May I suggest you review this help page: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1):

This script should point you in the correct direction:

```
t<-list()

for (i in  1:nrow(list)) {
   tempdf <- xmlToDataFrame(xmlParse(list$path[i])) #Read the data into a file
   tempdf$ID <- list$ID[i]
   t[[i]]<-tempdf
   
   if (i %% 10 == 0) {
      print(i)
   }  #print every 10th value to monitor progress of the loop
}

answer <- bind_rows(t) #Bind all into one file
```

Instead of a for loop, an `lapply` would also work here.  Without any sample data, this is untested.